# smooth scrolling - same implementation but different effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following odd problem:
My first page has the exactly same header and  section as the second page - my second page has smooth scrolling, my first page had it but lost it somehow.

I weren't able to track down how the template creator made those smoothing effects - does anybody know how something like this gets implemented? And has somebody maybe a clou why the first page hasn't this effect while they have the same implementations?

Thanks in advance,
Trusto

Edit:
I tracked down the implementation:

```
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js');
        include('js/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.min.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.srSmoothscroll({
                step: 150,
                speed: 800
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The page were it doesn't work is a php-file, the others are html.

Comment: would love if somebody could explain me what the var o=... does. Thanks!

Comment: `var o = ...` sets the variable `o` to contain an jQuery object of the `HTML` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - I implemented the unedited jquery-file in the first page which override the scrolling function. 
Thanks for your help.